# Why are reports not generated in App center after mobile test run

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, visual-studio-app-center

I have Jetpack compose UI testing tests in kotlin in android studio. Set them on azure pipeline to run from a App center test task and set Espresso framework. After the test are run there is no report generated in App center just logs and this is a issue because I use App center CLI to download the report and publish it in azure, but there is no report to download.
Any ideas why, checked online and it says that Jetpack Compose UI testing tests work the same as Espresso tests regarding the framework from the App center task from pipeline